# NowJS error! I can't get the example to work!

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was following along the tutorial at http://nowjs.com/doc when I encountered some errors.

```
 <html>
<head>
    <title>index.html</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"/>
    <script src="http://localhost:8080/NowJS/now.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var name = prompt("what is your name?","");
        now.receiveMessage = function(name,message){
            alert(name+" "+message);    

        };

        $('.butt').click(function(){
            alert($('#put').val());
            now.distributeMessage(name,$('#put').val());


        $('#put').val('');
    });
});

</script>
```

and for the server:

```
 var fs = require('fs');
var sys = require('sys');
var server = require('http').createServer(function(req,response){
    fs.readFile('index.html',function(err,data){
        response.writeHead(200);    
        response.write(data);
        response.end();
    });

});
server.listen(8080);
sys.print('woot');

var everyone = require('now').initialize(server);

everyone.now.distributeMessage = function(name, message){
    sys.print(name+"   "+message);
    everyone.now.receiveMessage(name,message);

};
```

I highly suspect it has something to do with my  tag since there isnt anything at /NowJS/now.js.
Can someone enlighten me on this part:

> On pages that you would like to use NowJS on, simply include this script tag in your HTML head: NowJS only works on pages that are served through the same http server instance that was passed into the initialize function above.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"/>
```

script tags can't be self-closed.

Answer (score 0):

In the docs the path in the script tag is lower-case, `/nowjs/now.js`, whereas in your snippet it is `/NowJS/now.js`, and so I guess this is the reason it doesn't work.